Sass 1.8 Migrating from @import broke mixins
I am trying to migrate my scss code to accommodate for 1.8. MIgrator tool is not helpful

Error: Undefined mixin.
     ╷
  12 │   @include roboto(700);

style.scss (root)
@use 'fonts';
@use 'mixins';
@use 'theme';
@use 'base';
@use 'client';

_base.scss (see above how its nested)
.type-logo {
  @extend .glow-blue;
  @apply text-[8rem];
  @include roboto(700);
}

@mixin roboto(...) was defined in _fonts.scss so why do i get the error

You are not importing in base.scss the module that exposes the roboto mixing. SASS can't find it, as expected.
Use @use to import the module that exposes the mixin.
@use "./fonts" as Fonts;

.type-logo {
  @extend .glow-blue;
  @apply text-[8rem];
  @include Fonts.roboto(700);
}

Please read the documentation about @use: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/
